# js access not public file using xmlhttp

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

To access files outside the public webspace you need a script in the public webspace that can fetch the contents from the private folder, e.g.

```
$allowedFiles = array(
    1 => '/path/to/private/space/on/server/file1.txt',
    2 => '/path/to/private/space/on/server/file2.txt',
    3 => '/path/to/private/space/on/server/file3.txt',
    4 => '/path/to/private/space/on/server/file4.txt',
);

$id = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

if (isset($allowedFiles[$id])) {
    readfile($allowedFiles[$id]);
}
```

Now when you do

xmlhttp.open("GET","file.php?id=4",false);  <==Notice last parameter is false (sync)
the script will send the content of

/path/to/private/space/on/server/file4.txt
to the client.

This piece of code work for small files, but when the file es bigger, i.e. 5 mgbytes, this code fails.

Any Idea?

Comment: Is there limits set in the ini file?

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini and try modifying the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` value to an higher value.

> Put all the files you want to have forced downloaded in a directory,
>   and set this in your .htaccess for that directory.

```
<Files *.*>
ForceType applicaton/octet-stream
</Files>
```

Found in this thread : http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?700250-PHP-File-%28Size%29-Download-Limit
There are some other solutions.